# Serialize unquoted property values

Tags: c#, javascript, json.net

Say I have this C# dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }
```

then I put some values inside

```
Parameters["param1"] = "val1";
Parameters["param2"] = "val2";
```

and finally I serialize it with

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);
writer.QuoteName = false;
writer.QuoteChar = '\'';
serializer.Serialize(writer, Parameters);
```

(I know there are quicker ways, but I need the quoting char to be a single quote and unquoted names).

The result is as expected:

```
{ 
   param1: 'val1', 
   param2: 'val2' 
}
```

But what if I want to include a property with an ***unquoted*** value, which may represent a function or an object name? For example, how do I get this result:

```
{ 
   param1: 'val1', 
   param2: 'val2',
   funcReference: someFunctionName,
   objName: valueWithoutQuotes
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Due to some responses about my JSON syntax saying it's not valid, let me clarify why I need stuff to be unquoted:

I'm using Knockoutjs for Javascript & HTML data-binding.
Therefore I need to write something like this - 
    `<div data-bind="something: 'value', event: funcName">...</div>`

I need single quotes so that it won't mess my HTML and I don't quote the properties names because of my personal style which is very common and is perfectly fine in Javascript (I'm not using it for data exchange).

I need some values to be unquoted so that Knockout will know it's a reference to a function, otherwise it'll treat it as a string.
And the names of the functions I'm generating on server, along with other properties and values.

I can of course always build and concat the JSON manually, but I'm looking for some automatic way.

Thanks!

Comment: am not sure why you want function names and class names to be unquoted, even if you want to search these function names using reflection, you can find the types using strings. JSON is supposed to be a string mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I've edited the question to clarify my needs. I'd be happy to know if you still have any solution.

Comment: from the JSON string do you programatically form the HTML content ?

Comment: since you are forming your own JSON string why did you choose JSON over XML serialization ?

Answer (score 2):

> (I know there are quicker ways, but I need the quoting char to be a
>   single quote and unquoted names

Sorry this is not valid JSON. In JSON all members should be double quoted (except numeric types) and you cannot have functions. There's no JSON serializer in .NET that will generate invalid JSON. If you need to generate invalid JSON you will have to do it by hand by using string concatenations, don't even try to use a serializer.

Here's the [grammar](http://www.json.org/) of a valid JSON encoded object. You have to stick with it. Don't just use the term *JSON* for any javascript syntax because JSON has very specific rules that need to be respected.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I've edited the question to clarify my needs. I'd be happy to know if you still have any solution.

Comment: I understand your needs but there's no automated way to achieve it using a JSON serializer.

Comment: OK, thanks. However JSON.NET technically does allow "illegal" JSON since it has the option for unquoted keys and single-quoted values, so I wondered if it also supports unquoted values.

Answer (score 0):

adding to my comment above, ideally it should be

```
{  
   "param1": "val1",  
   "param2": "val2", 
   "funcReference": "someFunctionName", 
   "objName": "valueWithoutQuotes" 
}
```

posting as answer since I could not post code in comments

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You cannot have single quotes.

Comment: that was a copy/paste mistake ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I've edited the question to clarify my needs. I'd be happy to know if you still have any solution.